# Multiple test case execution: I want to wait for entire page load in selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium

I used below code .Wait time is to be defined in milliseconds for each step. It will be good if we have better way of doing it (like wait till page loading is complete). please give me some answers.

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 0):

By default webdriver waits for a page to load to completion before moving forward to the next statement. But things such as AJAX calls (or) Javascript calls that trigger after a page is loaded and which alter the dom structure after loading of the page is complete cannot be dealt with by selenium automatically as part of page load completion.

You should instead consider using one of the helper methods within [ExpectedConditions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) API to wait for the element that determines that a page load has been complete.